# get text from text area in web drive io

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

To get value of UI textarea

I have DOM

```css
<textarea _ngcontent-yoo-c386="" pinputtextarea="" autoresize="true" readonly="" class="p-inputtextarea p-inputtext p-component p-element execute-textarea ng-pristine ng-valid p-inputtextarea-resizable ng-star-inserted p-filled ng-touched" rows="14" style="height: 277px; overflow: hidden;" xpath="1"></textarea>
```

```html
<textarea _ngcontent-yoo-c386="" pinputtextarea="" autoresize="true" readonly="" class="p-inputtextarea p-inputtext p-component p-element execute-textarea ng-pristine ng-valid p-inputtextarea-resizable ng-star-inserted p-filled ng-touched" rows="14" style="height: 277px; overflow: hidden;" xpath="1"></textarea>
```

Value of text area though not visible her is visble  in UI

Wante to get text out of it. tieed as bwloe is ot fetching text

let textAreaResponse = await element.getAttribute('value');

Comment: you can use the getText method to retrieve the visible text content of the textarea element.  let textAreaElement = await element.getText();